# How to show subject line for new messages in OS X Messages.app?

Tags: macos, messages, ui

Mavericks, if that matters. On the iPhone, there is a separate subject line before the main message, and on the Mac it shows (as on the phone) in bold at the top of the balloon. But when I want to make a new message on the Mac, I only have the body available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some [smart people](https://gist.github.com/getaaron/a9dc64b6ea2fa8299af6b7077f4386ae) have figured it out. It is in a hidden setting register.

Run `defaults write com.apple.MobileSMS MMSShowSubject 1` in the Terminal.
Then restart iMessage.

It should work.

Comment: `defaults delete com.apple.MobileSMS MMSShowSubject` should disable the feature.

Comment: This is great, but it's also worth noting it only works for macOS 11 Big Sur and later versions. (I tried on 10.15 Catalina and nope.) Likely is a result of Messages on macOS becoming based on code from the iOS version.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, you can't. I have looked everywhere for this feature.

I'd love for this answer to become wrong though.

Comment: AFIK even now in 2020 this feature still lacking! Would be awesome and probably not too hard to implement. Wish Messages on macOS would catch up in feature parity to messages in iOS/iPadOS!

Comment: Yeah, me too. As far as I can tell, yes, this still isn’t implemented.

Comment: Please see accepted solution!

Answer (score 0):

Well I was going to comment but apparently I don't have a reputation high enough to do that. This was the first result on DuckDuckGo based on my quarry. I am currently on OSX 12.7.3 Monterey Messages Version 14.0 (6000). I put the magic incantation listed above
" - Run defaults write com.apple.MobileSMS MMSShowSubject 1 - in the Terminal. Then restart iMessage."
I hit enter and quit and re-opened the app, finally!
As I have been using the subject field on first contact to input my full correct spelling of my name, Which usually means I have to start conversations on my phone or iPad.

Thanks and check up another I wish they implemented this from the beginning gripe.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/345225)

Comment: Well it wasn't just a thank you it was also that it works on 12 seven. Maybe I should've edited that put it on the bottom. I'm so glad comments working on this I might've had to post another question.